# Prove that $H^0(M,TM) \cong H^0(M_1,TM_1) \oplus H^0(M_2,TM_2).$ Roughly every vector field on $M$ is uniquely the sum of vector fields.

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

> For a complex manifold $N$, denote by $H^0(N,TN)$ the space of holomorphic vector fields on $N$. Let $M_i, i=1,2$ be *compact* complex manifolds, $M=M_1\times M_2$ their product. Prove that $$H^0(M,TM) \cong H^0(M_1,TM_1) \oplus H^0(M_2,TM_2).$$ Roughly every vector field on $M$ is uniquely the sum of a vector field on $M_1$ and a vector field on $M_2$. Give examples to show that if compactness is dropped then the result may or may not hold.

So I was thinking this follows from $\Gamma$ or $H^0$ preserving direct sums. Since $$TM=T(M_1\times M_2) \cong TM_1\oplus TM_2$$ applying $H^0$ we have that $$H^0(M,TM) \cong H^0(M_1, TM_1) \oplus H^0(M_2,TM_2)$$ but the latter part of the problem makes me wonder why this wouldn't work unless $M$ is compact? The proof for $TM \cong TM_1\oplus TM_2$ doesn't rely on compactness and I don't think the application of the cohomology or global section functor does neither?

Comment: Applying $H^0(M,-)$ only gives you $H^0(M,TM)\cong H^0(M,p_1^*TM_1)\oplus H^0(M,p_2^*TM_2)$ not $H^0(M_1,TM_1)\oplus H^0(M_2,TM_2)$.  Think about the vector field $z_1z_2\partial_1$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$, for example.

Comment: $z_1z_2\partial_1$ cannot be expressed as the sum of vector fields on $\Bbb C$? What if we restrict to a closed polydisc $\Delta \subset \Bbb C^2$? Then we would have the compactness condition, but I don't see how this would allow us to express $z_1z_2\partial_1$ as a sum. @user10354138

Comment: I don't think $M_1,M_2$ are allowed to have boundaries.

Comment: Hint: Without assuming compactness, the pullback $p_{1}^{*}TM_{1}$ is trivial when restricted to a slice $\{p\} \times M_{2}$; the total space is $M_{2} \times T_{p}M_{1}$. A section of this pullback, restricted to $\{p\} \times M_{2}$, may therefore be viewed as a holomorphic mapping from $M_{2}$ into the complex vector space $T_{p}M_{1}$. <> Now, if $M_{2}$ is _compact_, we know something about holomorphic maps from $M_{2}$ to a vector space....

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks for the answer again. As you might have guessed this problem is also from your notes which I'm studying. Do you by any chance happen to know some other material which you could recommend alongside for a beginner in the topic of complex manifolds? I have quite a bit of background in smooth manifolds, but I'm really struggling with the exercises.

Comment: Students of my cohort generally read Chern's _Complex Manifolds Without Potential Theory_, Wells' _Differential Analysis..._, Griffiths and Harris' _Principles of Algebraic Geometry_, and a scattering of others. <> A number of people at MSE have asked questions about Daniel Huybrecht's book, and one or two others whose authors I don't recall offhand. <> At least some of the exercises in _A Beginner's Guide..._ are admittedly less friendly than they could have been. If I see you've asked about anything where I recall a useful hint, I'll post or comment. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this isn't partially-answered-in-the-comments, here's a detailed sketch.

First, a diagram in the style of Kobayashi:

[image: The tangent bundle of a product manifold, restricted to a slice over a point of the first factor]

For $k = 1$, $2$, let $\pi_{k}:M \to M_{k}$ denote the projection map. There is an isomorphism of holomorphic vector bundles over $M$,
$$
T(M_{1} \times M_{2}) = \pi_{1}^{*}TM_{1} \oplus \pi_{2}^{*} TM_{2}.
$$
A holomorphic vector field $X$ on the product, a.k.a. a holomorphic section of the left-hand bundle, may therefore be identified with an ordered pair $(X_{1}, X_{2})$ of holomorphic sections of the respective pullback summands on the right.

*A priori*, each component $X_{k}$ is defined on the product $M$ and takes values in the pullback bundle $\pi_{k}^{*}TM_{k}$. It suffices to show $X_{k}$ may be identified with a holomorphic vector field on $M_{k}$; loosely, that "each section is constant in the other variable."

Generally (i.e., without compactness), the pullback $\pi_{1}^{*}TM_{1}$ is holomorphically trivial when restricted to a slice $\{p\} \times M_{2}$ (fibers shown in gray); the total space is $M_{2} \times T_{p}M_{1}$, equipped with projection to $M_{2}$. A section of $\pi_{1}^{*}TM_{1}$, restricted to $\{p\} \times M_{2}$, may therefore be viewed as a holomorphic mapping from $M_{2}$ into the complex vector space $T_{p}M_{1}$.

Because $M_{2}$ is compact, every holomorphic map from $M_{2}$ to $T_{p}M_{1}$ is constant. (This is the point where compactness and "holomorphic" are essential.) Particularly, $X_{1}$ restricted to $\{p\} \times M_{2}$ is constant.

On the other hand, for each point $q$ in $M_{2}$, the restriction of $\pi_{1}^{*}TM_{1}$ to $M_{1} \times \{q\}$ is isomorphic to $TM_{1}$ as a holomorphic vector bundle. Particularly, $X_{1}$ restricted to $M_{1} \times \{q\}$ may be identified with a holomorphic vector field on $M_{1}$.

Finally, since the section $X_{1}$ on $M$ is "constant in $q$," it may be identified with a section of $TM_{1}$.

The same argument with the roles of the factors swapped shows $X_{2}$ may be identified with a section of $TM_{2}$.

<>

To give a non-compact manifold where the same decomposition holds, it suffices to find a non-compact manifold on which every holomorphic function is constant.

> Examples include an arbitrary holomorphic surface with one point removed, or any holomorphic manifold with a submanifold of complex codimension at least two removed, by Hartog's extension theorem.

The comment of user10354138 gives an example where the stated decomposition of vector fields does not hold.